# where is this toggle() function coming from in angular code?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I'm using this code for a side nav: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-sidenav-responsive?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html

its uses this from template reference variable **#sidenav**

```
<a href="#" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">Vodafone Airtime</a>
```

I want to know where is this **.toggle()** function coming from, its a property of the sidenav object? where can I view all these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a method of Angular Material's sidenav. This component is assigned to a variable named `sidenav` here:

```
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav [(mode)]="over" [(opened)]="opened" class="bottom-to-top">
```

For further reading on sidenav's methods, inputs, outputs and properties, best start with the official docs:
https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api